# Return alias used to execute application

Tags: python, bash, unix

Is there a way to echo the alias used to run the script instead of the actual .py name?

From Bash

```
user$alias TESTA='/home/user/script.py'
user$TESTA arg1 arg2
```

sys.argv[0] returns /home/user/script.py
I'm Looking for something to return TESTA instead?

Comment: I don't think aliases are inherited by the python process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably out of luck: aliases are ephemeral, the shell substitutes them *before* invoking the process.

In fact, on Linux, even `/proc/$$/cmdline` doesn’t contain the alias any more. You can verify this by saving the following code as `proc.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

with open(f'/proc/{os.getpid()}/cmdline', 'r') as cmdline:
    print(cmdline.read().replace('\0', ' '))
```

And then invoking it as follows:

```sh
chmod +x proc.py
alias foo=proc.py
foo
```

The output of this will be something along the lines of

```
python3 ./x.py
```

… no mention of the alias `foo`.

If you want to be able to call your code with different names, use *symbolic links* instead. The following works:

```sh
ln -s proc.py foobar
./foobar
```

Now your “alias” (the symbolic link path) will be accessible as `sys.argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` returns a list of the arguments passed to the script being executed.
`sys.argv[0]` will always return the path of the script being executed. To access `arg1` you would use `sys.argv[1]` and to access `arg2` - `sys.argv[2]`